# Which activation or transfer function is suitable to classify 3 type of data?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm trying to train a MLP to classify Iris dataset using ABC. From the code of ABC I get the optimal weights and biases I entered them to the code of testing it gave me 5 right classification and 10 wrong I think the fault in my code is in training process Which activation or transfer function is suitable to classify 3 type of data?

I get the output through this

```
trin= [4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2;
 4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2;
 5.4 3.4 1.5 0.4;
 5.2 4.1 1.5 0.1;
 5.5 4.2 1.4 0.2;
 5.7 2.6 3.5 1;
 5.5 2.4 3.8 1.1;
 5.5 2.4 3.7 1;
 5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2;
 6 2.7 5.1 1.6;
 6.7 3.3 5.7 2.1;
 7.2 3.2 6 1.8;
 6.2 2.8 4.8 1.8;
 6.1 3 4.9 1.8;
 6.4 2.8 5.6 2.1
 ];
 trout=[-1;-1;-1;-1;-1;
   0;0;0;0;0;
   1;1;1;1;1];
 inp=size(trin,2);
 out=size(trout,2);
 hidden=2;


 x=[[1,1.970,-2,4,1,-3.450,5,-5,-2.650,3.300,4,-2,-1.920]];
iw = reshape(x(1:hidden*inp),hidden,inp);
b1 = reshape(x(hidden*inp+1:hidden*inp+hidden),hidden,1);
lw =           
 reshape(x(hidden*inp+hidden+1:hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out),out,hidden);


 b2=reshape(x
 (hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out+1:hidden*inp+hidden+hidden*out+out)
 ,out,1);

y = tanh(tanh(trin*iw'+repmat(b1',size(trin,1),1))*lw'+
repmat(b2',size(trin,1),1));
e = gsubtract(trout,y);

tind = vec2ind(trout);
yind = vec2ind(y);
percentErrors = sum(tind ~= yind)/numel(tind);
```

x vextor is the weights and biases witch I get from ABC optimization algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really perform multi-class classification with a tanh output. For this a softmax activation is used, where the output is a vector of thre elements, corresponding to probabilities for each class.

Comment: no the output is just one value either 1 or 0 or -1 reffering to each class for example if the input is [[4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2] the output should be -1  because I normalize my dataset and use only 2 neuron in hidden layer and 1 neuron in output layer

Comment: @samsam Still that's not common usage, and my answer still applies. Softmax is generally superior.

Comment: @samsam Edit your original question, but I am not sure what else you are expecting.

Comment: I use an Approximate same code for training on the other 135 sample

Comment: I update something in the code of training and get the following output in testing


-1.0000   -1.0000   -1.0000   -1.0000   -1.0000   -0.0179    0.0183    0.0010   -0.0001    0.9986    0.9954    0.9952    0.9165    0.6627    0.9993


insted of 


-1    -1    -1    -1    -1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1


can I consider this as good result ???